# unable to load shared object quantreg.so

Tags: r, linux

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.3                         
year           2015                        
month          12                          
day            10                          
svn rev        69752                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
nickname       Wooden Christmas-Tree
```

I am trying to use RStudio for data mining. The last time I was using R only, I didn't have this problem. Then I rebuilt the R packages in my machine to use RStudio
and installed  the package `FactoMineR` to perform PCA. When I run
`library('FactoMineR')` or `library(FactoMineR)`, I get this error:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/ci/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/quantreg/libs/quantreg.so':
  libRlapack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘FactoMineR’
```

When I tried to reinstall this package, I got the same error, so it is not just the mistake of `library()`.

Comment: Are you able to load this package in vanilla R?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, thanks for your reply, and what is the vanilla R? An IDE or somewhat? sorrry I'm a newbie.

Comment: Outside Rstudio. If you run R from the console.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the package `quantreg`?

Comment: This sentence makes no sense: _Then I rebuilt the R packages in my machine to use RStudio_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stibu, I tried to reinstall the Quantreg packages, and it worked, but there are some other problems.
I will reopen a question.
Thank you all

Comment: This is actually not an answer, is it? Why not editing it to describe what finally worked for you, even though it's three years later?